# crashlytics android native crashes failed to report on dashboard

Tags: c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, native, crashlytics-android

I am integrating crashlytics in android App to get the native crashes. I have followed instructions on link : 
https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk

I am compiling project with crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease or crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug and I can see CSYM in build folder but i am not sure if its getting uploaded or not.
Also, I do not see option to upload csym to crashlytics manually.

I crashed app in c++ code but crash is not reported to dashboard but JAVA crashes are getting reported to dashboard successfully.

I can see below exception in log in crashlyticscore:

```
D/CrashlyticsCore(8077): Could not generate ID for file /data/data/com.package.dummy/cache/1501670890290.dex (deleted)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/app/com.package.dummy-1/lib/arm/1501670890290.dex (deleted): open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.Sha1FileIdStrategy.getFileSHA(Sha1FileIdStrategy.java:28)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.Sha1FileIdStrategy.createId(Sha1FileIdStrategy.java:17)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.BinaryImagesConverter.parseProcMapsJson(BinaryImagesConverter.java:67)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.BinaryImagesConverter.convert(BinaryImagesConverter.java:33)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.NativeFileUtils.processBinaryImages(NativeFileUtils.java:85)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.NativeFileUtils.binaryImagesJsonFromFile(NativeFileUtils.java:72)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.NativeFileUtils.binaryImagesJsonFromDirectory(NativeFileUtils.java:62)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.finalizeMostRecentNativeCrash(CrashlyticsController.java:883)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.access$1500(CrashlyticsController.java:67)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$16.call(CrashlyticsController.java:953)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$16.call(CrashlyticsController.java:943)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
01-02 12:19:58.499: D/CrashlyticsCore(8077):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
```

Comment: Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: @Jordan No not yet. Crashlytics replied to the query and said that this isssue is fixed in latest update. I tried in it too but still getting same exception. Will contact them again and if i get any update, will update you.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Same stacktrace. Could you point me to  the bug report/ support so I can ask them too.